# How to implement this using map/filter

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I'm supposed to come up with a function `and::[Bool]->Bool`, where `(and xs)` is True only if xs containst no False elements.

I am perfectly able to write this using recursion. I even tried it using map, BUT map ALWAYS return a list, which conflicts my return type.

Here's my code using recursion: (it works just fine)

```
isTrue::[Bool]->Bool
isTrue []       =True
isTrue (x:xs)
 | (x == True)  =isTrue(xs)
 | otherwise    =False
```

I tried doing this with map: (this will never work)

```
and::[Bool]->Bool
and xs = map (True ==) xs
```

So how in the world can I use map, filter or foldr to implement this crazy function? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter `True` values and check if the result is an empty list:

```
and' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and' = null . filter (== False)
```

More classic approach using `foldr`:

```
and'' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and'' = foldr (&&) True
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work for empty lists. The first one is insufficiently lazy.

Comment: @dfeuer, corrected. I don't say that the first solution is perfect. Question was: 'So how in the world can I use map, filter or foldr to implement this crazy function?'. So I showed how to do it different ways.

Comment: @dfeuer As a non-expert, I'm curious what you mean when you say it's insufficiently lazy. It works on infinite lists.

Comment: @MattAdams, we'd expect `and (False:undefined)` to be `False`, but with the `filter`-based definition above, it's `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. A lazier solution would be `and' = null . filter (== False)`

Comment: @MattAdams, great idea, you could post it as an alternative answer ;-)

Comment: @Mark I think that could reasonably be considered a correction of your basic approach there.

Comment: @dfeuer, I'll add that correction and make it community wiki. I'm just so often inattentive ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Consider also `takeWhile` in a similar fashion as filter, yet halting the filtering once the first `False` is encountered, as follows,

```
and' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and' xs = xs == takeWhile (== True) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` is the way to go:

There are various ways to get to that. The first is to think about folding as inserting a binary operation between pairs of elements:

```
foldr c n [x1,x2,x3,...,xn] =
    x1 `c` (x2 `c` (x3 `c` (... `c` (xn `c` n))))
```

So in this case,

```
foldr (&&) True [x1,x2,x3,...,xn] =
    x1 && x2 && x3 && ... && xn && True
```

Note that `&&` is right associative, so we don't need the parentheses there.

Another approach is to figure out how to convert the recursive form you gave into a fold. The thing to read to see how this works in general is Graham Hutton's "A Tutorial on the Universality and Expressiveness of Fold".

Start with your recursive form:

```
and::[Bool]->Bool
and []       =True
and (x:xs)
 | (x == True)  = and (xs)
 | otherwise    = False
```

Now there's no reason to ask if `x==True` because that's actually just the same as testing `x` directly. And there's no need for extra parentheses around a function argument. So we can rewrite that like this:

```
and []        = True
and (x:xs)
  | x         = and xs
  | otherwise = False
```

Now let's see if we can write this as a fold:

```
and xs = foldr c n xs
```

Because `and [] = True` we know that `n = True`:

```
and xs = foldr c True xs
```

Now look at the recursive case:

```
and (x:xs)
  | x         = and xs
  | otherwise = False
```

You can see that this depends only on `x` and on `and xs`. This means that we *will* be able to come up with a `c` so the fold will work out right:

```
c x r
  | x         = r
  | otherwise = False
```

`r` is the result of applying `and` to the whole rest of the list. But what is this `c` function? It's just `(&&)`!

So we get

```
and xs = foldr (&&) True xs
```

At each step, `foldr` passes `(&&)` the current element and the result of folding over the rest of the list.

We don't actually need that `xs` argument, so we can write

```
and = foldr (&&) True
```